# How to convert outlook macro to .exe

Tags: vba, outlook, exe

Situation: I want to click on an exe file than going to outlook > developers > macro to run a macro. How do you make a macro into an executable program(exe). Any help would be great :)

Comment: VB is an advanced version of VBA. There is a learning curve but it is not enormous. For single-user applications VB is free with the "Community" version of Visual Studio. VB compiles to executable programs.  VB can access the data of any version of any Office product via its InterOp. Each access via the InterOp is slow, perhaps because it is so flexible.  Outlook does not like outside program accessing its email data.  The user will have to give permission.

Comment: Alternatively you could create an Excel workbook which runs a macro at start-up and quits when finished.  An Excel workbook can read from and write to Outlook although the user still has to give permission to access email data.

Comment: People will tell you VB is slow with Office. This is true if you want to use the InterOp repeatedly. I once helped someone who had an enormous Excel workbook and wanted to do lots of processing and then output the results to text files. Extrapolating up from a small amount of processing suggested the total task would take over 40 days. By loading the data into a VB program, I completed the processing in 50 minutes. VB's equivalent of Forms has far more control types allowing much more attractive user interfaces. Its processing is blinding fast compared with VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I have found out, you need to use a development tool like visual studios in order to create an executable program.